# webViewDidFinishLoad blocks main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just noticed that webViewDidFinishLoad method blocks an entire application, so i can't even touch any buttons.

I need to parse the resulting page of the UIWebView and it can take a lot of time. So what's the best way to parse it without blocking an entire application? Maybe create another thread?

Answer (score 3):

Parse it in the background using GCD:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // Get the contents from the UIWebView (in the main thread)
    NSString *data = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Parse the data here

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Update the UI here

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1e507400: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov Get the contents in the main thread, then parse that contents in the background.  See my edit.

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov You are accessing the webview from the background thread; you cannot interact with the UI in anyway outside of the main thread.  See my (second) edit.

Comment: @trojanfoe what if the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString is taking long time? Can I load that process in background? In my case that's the problem, evaluating the Javascript and waiting for the answer. In my case I dont want to wait more than 5 seconds, in that scenario I would like to kill the process and do something else. Can I?

Comment: @CrisR I'm not in a position to test this, but I'd give it a try using GCD etc.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, I solved it doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28402685/4085636

Comment: Nowadays... `dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ /* UI updates here */ });`

Answer (score 0):

It's normal `-webViewDidFinishLoad` to be called on the main thread. What you need to do is to get the html and do the parsing operation by dispatching it to another queue.

Comment: can I call the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in background? In my case that's the process which is taking long time, and in case is taking more than 5 seconds, I would like to kill it and do something else.